# performance when converting an integer into its bytes characters representation in python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, type-conversion

To be specific I need to convert an integer, say `9999`, into bytes, `b'9999'` in python 2.6 up to python 3.x

In python 2.x I do

```
b'%s'%n
```

while in python 3.x

```
('%s'%n).encode()
```

Performance in python 2.6

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> Timer('b"%s"%n','n=9999').timeit()
0.24728001750963813
```

Performance in python 3.2

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> Timer('("%s"%n).encode()','n=9999').timeit()
0.534475012767416
```

Assuming my benchmarks are set up correctly, that is an hefty penalty in python 3.x.

Is there a way to improve performance to close the gap with 2.6/2.7?

Maybe via the [cython](http://cython.org/) route?

This is the generator function I'm trying to optimize. It is called over and over with `args` being a list of strings, bytes or numbers:

```
def pack_gen(self, args, encoding='utf-8'):
    crlf = b'\r\n'
    yield ('*%s\r\n'%len(args)).encode(encoding)
    for value in args:
        if not isinstance(value, bytes):
            value = ('%s'%value).encode(encoding)
        yield ('$%s\r\n'%len(value)).encode(encoding)
        yield value
        yield crlf
```

The function is called in this way

```
b''.join(pack_gen(args))
```

Comment: Why does it need to be bytes?

Comment: It is a hefty penalty, since you need to first convert it to a string and then to bytes. I don't see a way around that. The question is if it really is relevant. Is this actually a major performance penalty in your application?

Comment: Yes it is. It is inside a long loop in function which is constantly called.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a little bit better results using repr() with Python 3.2:

```
>>> Timer('repr(n).encode()','n=9999').timeit()
0.32432007789611816
>>> Timer('("%s" % n).encode()','n=9999').timeit()
0.44790005683898926
```

But of course it is not as flexible as `"%s" % n`.

I've also checked Python 3.3.0a3 hoping that [PEP393](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/) will speed up conversion a little but surprisingly I've got worse results than in 3.2:

```
>>> Timer('repr(n).encode()','n=9999').timeit()
0.35951611599921307
>>> Timer('("%s"%n).encode()','n=9999').timeit()
0.4658188759985933
```

Finally, following:

```
>>> Timer('str(n).encode()','n=9999').timeit()
0.49958825100111426
```

shows that most of the cost may be from function call overhead (from result above I'm assuming that Python implementation of `str()` for integer type calls `repr()` internally). So if you need to optimize at this level, then as you suggested, replacing whole code block using cython may be the way to go. Or better yet show us the loop you are trying to optimize, as there may be many other approaches to speed it up.

Comment: I added a use case in the question body.